# subprocess piping output on Windows

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I've got this piece of code that works fine on Linux but fails on Windows. Process is created fine, but I get an error and nothing is read from pipe:

```
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-u', self.file_to_run,
                                   '-s', '-g', '-i', self.input_file],
                                   universal_newlines=True,
                                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    ...
    out = p.stdout.readline().rstrip()
```

Error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bench.py", line 59, in <module>
    multi.add_process()
  File "bench.py", line 47, in add_process
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "c:\python\v2.5.1-ast3\...\lib\subprocess.py", line 615, in __init__
    self.stdout = os.fdopen(c2pread, 'rU', bufsize)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I actually create multiple such processes and based on their output calculate some values, but that is irrelevant. What I need to do is, run the script with certain arguments multiple times and parse the data piped from stdout of each process.

Comment: Does the command work on the shell? Stupid question, I know, but just making sure. I usually build the command string and output it, then run it manually to make sure it'll work. After that, I usually use shlex to handle the argument parsing.

Comment: @Marin: ping! Have you solved that problem?

Comment: @gurneyalex unfortunately, no...

Answer (score 0):

try using `sys.executable` instead of `'python'` in your subprocess args. I think this is because Python is not in the PATH on Windows.

Also check the value of `self.file_to_run` and `self.input_file` which must be strings and not None or strange stuff, but this probably won't cause an `OSError`.